# Validate form fields with Ajax calls to a server - Learning Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I need to validate my form fields using Ajax.
What I have right now is a javascript validation.
I was wondering if it would be possible to re-use my javascript code and implement Ajax

**html form**

```
<form method="post" action="ajax/validation.php" class="ibm-row-form" id="registerform">
        <h2 class="ibm-inner-subhead">Basic registration information</h2>                               
        <p>
               First name: <span class="ibm-required">*</span><br/>
               <input id="firstName" name ="firstName" size="36" type="text" onblur=" validateFirstName();" />
               <span id="errorFName" class="error">First name is required</span>        
        </p>
        <p>                         
               Last name:<span class="ibm-required">*</span><br/>
               <input name="lastName" id="lastName" size="36" type="text" onblur="validateLastName();" />
               <span id="errorLName" class="error">Last name is required</span>
        </p>
        <input id="ibm-submit" name="ibm-submit" class="ibm-btn-arrow-pri" value="Register" type="submit" />
        <input value="Cancel" type="button" name="ibm-cancel" class="ibm-btn-cancel-sec" onclick="window.location(window.location.href = '#')" /> 
</form>
```

**JavaScript validation (no Ajax)**

```
function validateFirstName(){
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    if(fName==""){
          errorFName.style.visibility = "visible";
          return false;
    } 
    errorFName.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function validateLastName(){
    var LName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    if(LName==""){
         errorLName.style.visibility = "visible";
         return false;
    } 
    errorLName.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

**Ajax validation (That's what I'm trying to do)**

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function(){
       var that = $(this);
       url = that.attr('action');
       method = that.attr('method');
       data = {};
       that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
             var that = $(this),
             name = that.attr('name'),
             value = that.val();
             data[name] = value;
       });
       $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: type,
             data : data,
             success: function(response){
                   console.log(response);
             }
       });
       return false;
});
```

So, how should I approach a solution to implement my Ajax inside my Javascript code. How can I merge these codes in order to validate the form fields?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add the no ajax part in the ajax validation, like this :

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function(){
   var that = $(this);
   url = that.attr('action');
   method = that.attr('method');
   data = {};
   that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){
         var that = $(this),
         name = that.attr('name'),
         value = that.val();
         data[name] = value;
   });

   // CODE ADDED HERE
   if(validateFirstName() && validateLastName()){
       $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: type,
           data : data,
           success: function(response){
               console.log(response);
           }
        });
    }
    return false;
});

function validateFirstName(){
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    if(fName==""){
        errorFName.style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    } 
    errorFName.style.visibility = "hidden";
    // CODE ADDED HERE
    return true;
}

function validateLastName(){
    var LName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    if(LName==""){
        errorLName.style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    } 
    errorLName.style.visibility = "hidden";
    // CODE ADDED HERE
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't do the ajax validation when I do that.

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida  what do you mean by Ajax validation? You want to validate in the server side, but submit with Ajax?

Comment: i need to validate the form fields with ajax calls to a server.

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida Can you make  it more clear? You want to  validate  the  input before the user submit?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's just the assignment notes from the professor is very poor. But from my understanding, I have to do the ajax validation in the servlet.

Comment: I think he wants something like this: 
<td>Company <span class="highlight">*</span></td>
<td> <input id="company" name="1" size="35" class="textbox"
type="text" onblur="validateCompany();">
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span class="error" id="companyMessage"></span></td>
function validateCompany() {
var f = document.getElementById("companyMessage");
var t = document.getElementById("company");
var url = "http://localhost:8080/CodeCSE336/HelloAjaxText?company="
+ t.value;
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.onreadystatechange = companyValidation;
req.send(null);
}

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida Ok, I means what you says. your codes seem to work. so you have other questions?